# open new url window without knowing the url Selenium webDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, automation

in all Selenium cod examples if I want open webdriver specific website page its goes like this

> `chromeDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(sitename);

but now I have a problem that when I click on webpage that I'm testing its open new website (3th pary website) and I cant know the URL in advance.
so anyone know ,how can I know what is the URL in the new page that opens  ??

Answer (score 0):

you can access the current url with `driver.Url`.

http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/?topic=html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_Remote_RemoteWebDriver_Url.htm

Comment: this is not remote driver , I'm running the cod locally

Comment: all drivers extend remote driver and have the driver.Url property.

Comment: in what you sent i have no property that can go to url without knowing it in advance . maybe I'm missing something ?

Comment: It can take the url if the webdriver is on specific page . but my problem is that I'm standing on one page , then clicking on some filed and its open a new page that i need to know its url

Comment: You're opening the new page in another window or something? You can navigate to other windows as well, then get that driver.Url, then go back to your original window and use it there.

Comment: How can i navigate the driver to this new window that opened  if I don't know this window Url

Comment: http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/?topic=html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_Remote_RemoteWebDriver_WindowHandles.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com");
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='nav-tags']"))).sendKeys(Keys.SHIFT).click().build().perform();

// You have opened your unknown site in a new window till now

String currentWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
ArrayList < String > windowHandles = new ArrayList < String > (driver.getWindowHandles());
    for (int i = 0; i < windowHandles.size(); i++) {
    if (windowHandles.get(i).equals(currentWindowHandle)) {

        //SwitchTo new Window
        driver.switchTo().window(windowHandles.get(i + 1));

        //Do your stuff like get URL that tou need
        System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

        //Close the newly opened window
        driver.close();
    }
}
driver.switchTo().window(currentWindowHandle);
```

Here this will open tags window in a new window and get the URL of that window, Assuming that is what you want.